# Angular material tabs: wrong positioning in safari

Tags: safari, tabs, angular-material

I am using angular material tabs. I have 3 tabs and a headline above them. It works fine in firefox and chrome but not i safari, where the headline gets positioned on top of the tabs instead of above them. Does someone know why this happens and how I could solve it?

Firefox and chrome:
[image: Firefox and Chrome]
Safari:
[image: Safari]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fault in our code. The text (headline) was in a column that was in a column, that had `flex="100"`. Apparently Safari does not like columns in columns while Chrome and Firefox can handle it fine.

When changing one of the columns to a row the positioning worked in safari.